# The commutator of two subgroups

Tags: group-theory

Let $G=D \ltimes C$ be a finite non-nilpotent group, where $D=N_G(B)=(A \ltimes B)$ is a maximal subgroup of $G$ such that $A \cong \Bbb{Z}_r$, $B=B_1 \times B_2 \cong \Bbb{Z}_s \times \Bbb{Z}_s$ and $C \cong \Bbb{Z}_t$ such that $r,s,t$ are distinct prime numbers. Also assume that the following assumption is hold:

(1). $[B,C] \neq 1 $

(2). $B_2C \ntrianglelefteq G $

(3). $A \ntrianglelefteq D$

(4). $CA \ntrianglelefteq G$, and is cyclic.

(5). $B_1 =C_B(C)$

(6). $C$ is a minimal normal subgroup of $G$.

Now i want to conclude that $[B_1,A]=1$.

${\bf  {My work}}$: I said that since $AC$ is cyclic, $[A,C]=1$ and since $B_1 =C_B(C)$, $[B_1 , C]=1$. Thus we have $[B_1,C,A]=[C,A,B_1]=1$, and so by a well-known lemma, $[A,B_1,C]=1$ i.e. $[[A,B_1] , C]=1$.

On the other hand, by First isomorphism Theorem, I see that $D / C_D(C)$ is cyclic, because ${\rm Aut}(C) \cong {\Bbb{Z}_t}^*$, where $D:=(A \ltimes B)$.
But I can't conclude $[B_1,A]=1$.

Comment: If I have managed to read the assumptions correctly, then $X \times Y$ is a counterexample, with $X$ dihedral of order $6$, $Y$ nonabelian of order $21$, $r=2$, $s=3$, $t=7$.

Comment: Really you said $B_2C $ is normal in $G$. But maybe $B_2 C $ is non-normal in $G$.

Comment: You can choose $B_2$ such that $B_2C \unlhd G$.

Comment: So let $B_2 C $ is non-normal in $G4. I edited question

Comment: As I said, you can choose $B_2$ such that $B_2C \unlhd G$, so your extra condition does not make any difference. What you want to prove is false.

Comment: It is a part of a problem that my teacher give me, may be i dont insert assumption correctly

Comment: give me a few moment until edited correctly

Answer (score 1):

OK, here is my claimed counterexample in more detail. You can check that it satisfies all of your conditions.

$G = X \times Y$, where $X = \langle a,b_1 \mid a^2=b_1^3=1, a^{-1}b_1a=b_1^{-1} \rangle$ is dihedral of order $6$, and $Y = \langle b_2,c \mid b_2^3=c^7=1, b_2^{-1}cb_2=c^2 \rangle$ is nonabelian of order $21$.

We have $r=2$, $s=3$, $t=7$, $A= \langle a \rangle$, $B = \langle b_1, b_2 \rangle$, and $C= \langle c \rangle$.

We have $B_1 = C_B(C) = \langle b_1 \rangle$,  and in order to get your condition $B_2C \not\unlhd G$, we define $B_2 = \langle b_1b_2 \rangle$.

Then $[A,B_1] = B_1 \ne 1$.

Comment: No I am certainly not going to delete my answer!